# Ionic Cordova Branch deep link clicked from Facebook returns `+clicked_branch_link: false`

Tags: ios, facebook, ionic3, deep-linking, branch.io

I have an Ionic 3 app and I am using Branch for deep linking and all works fine except for when a deep link is clicked from within the Facebook app. Clicking on the link does open my app, but it does not recognize it as being clicked on from a branch link - the data is shown as `{"+clicked_branch_link":false, "+is_first_session":false}`

I need it to recognize it as a branch link as I am passing additional data.

I have looked into several other posts suggesting that the issue is related to using a test key in a live environment, but I am confident that this is not the issue as I can click on a link from an email and it works fine.

I can even create a link that is shared via email (which works when I click on it), then share that link on facebook and then click on it which doesn't work.

How can I get clicking on the link from within Facebook work the same as from email?

Answer (score 0):

Man,

Thank you for reaching out!

This is likely be caused by the Facebook **scraper** not functioning properly. ([https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/. https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linked-ads/facebook-ads-faq/#issues-reading-facebook-app-links](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/.%C2%A0https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linked-ads/facebook-ads-faq/#issues-reading-facebook-app-links)). It is advised to first view existing scrape information and then compare it to new scrape information.

However, if this does not work, please do submit a support ticket to support@branch.io so that we may investigate further. There may be information that we need that should not be shared publicly.

Cheers,

Joie

Comment: Thanks Joie. I tried but it didn't work. I'll open a ticket with branch